# Tapping site icon on stackexchange.com increases page width

Tags: bug, status-deferred, design, stackexchange.com

Stackexchange.com page with site tiles looks normal initially:

> [image]

But if you tap on any tile from the right side the page width will be increased to make popup visible:

> [image]

In the same time top bar still has old width, and the page entirely looks weird.